# Golang Iris: Initialize parent controller's model to child controller's model

Tags: go, go-iris

I understand that Go is not an object-oriented language but I'm trying to implement a inheritance structure in my Iris controllers as suggested by [this](https://medium.com/@simplyianm/why-gos-structs-are-superior-to-class-based-inheritance-b661ba897c67) article. My main motivation for doing so is to avoid repetition. So far, it has been working for me. Take a look at the following code for example.

```
// APIController.go (package Controllers)
type APIController struct {
    mvc.C
}
func (c *APIController) Post(data map[string][]string) ([]byte, error) {
    data_parsed := c.ParseFormData(data)
    return json.Marshal(data_parsed)
}

// UserController.go  (package Controllers)
type UserController struct {
    mvc.C
    *APIController
}

func (c *UserController) Post() ([]byte, error) {
    return c.APIController.Post(c.Ctx.FormValues())
}
```

So far so good.

But I'm finding it difficult to replicate the same strategy for Models. This is what I've done so far

```
// Model.go (package Models)
type Model struct {
    Id         string `json:"_id"`
    Created_at string `json:"created_at"`
    Updated_at string `json:"updated_at"`
    Deleted_at string `json:"deleted_at"`
}
// implements further set of functions to be used by 'child' models...

// User.go (package Models)
type User struct {
    *Model

    First_name string `json:"first_name"`
    Last_name  string `json:"last_name"`
    Email      string `json:"email"`
    Username   string `json:"username"`
    Password   string `json:"password"`
    Last_login string `json:"last_login"`
}


// APIController.go (package Controllers)
type APIController struct {
    mvc.C
    Model Models.Model
}

// UserController.go  (package Controllers)
type UserController struct {
    mvc.C
    *APIController
}

func (c *UserController) Post() ([]byte, error) {
    c.APIController.Model = new(Models.User) //WRONG!
    return c.APIController.Post(c.Ctx.FormValues())
}
```

As you can see, the APIController is expecting type `Models.Model` while UserController is passing `*Models.User`. The end goal is to have a generic model in APIController that any model from any controller and then is able to call all the functions defined in Models.Model so that I don't have to call those function everywhere.

Is it possible to do so? If not, what might be the best approach to avoid repeating the code?

**Update**

By using inheritance and single parent model and using that in parent `APIController`, I want to avoid replicating my filter/CRUD logic. For example, inside `UserController`, if I want to save a record, then instead of using `User.Save(input_data)` inside `UserController`, the `Save` should ideally be defined inside `Models.Model` and from `APIController`, I'm able to call `Model.Save(input_data)` rather than making the same call from child controllers individually.

Comment: I understand that you want `c.APIController.Model` to contain a model of any type, but how do you want to use the model?

Comment: @md2perpe updated the question for precise usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make `Model` an interface instead of a struct. Have it contain all methods that should be common to all models:

```
type Model interface {
    // Common methods
}
```

Then, as long as `User` implements all those methods, you can have

```
c.APIController.Model = new(Models.User) // Now works!
```

One of the common methods could be `Save`. Otherwise make `Save` a non-method:

```
func Save(m Model) error {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was experimenting along the lines of defining `APIController.Model` as an `interface{}` but that method had its shortcomings. Yours seems like better option.